# iTunes on dashboard

Tags: macos, osx-lion, itunes, dashboard

I am somewhat a newbie in OS X, and I just discovered the dashboard and amount of widgets I can [download](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/) to it. And my tow questions are:

1. Is there a "iTunes widget" that plays music and controls it from the dashboard rather having an open program?
2. Can I program one? Is that OK with apple's guidelines\policy? (Or at least tell me where to look to get the answer to that)

## Edit

The reason I want that is because I  have quite a bit of open programs in the doc. And I want to get rid of the iTunes, because it is really just there to play music, and I barely click on it.

Comment: So is your real problem that you want to hide iTunes from the dock?

Comment: Yes it is, and these are charters so I can post the comment.

Comment: See here: [How do you hide the Finder from the list of applications when Command-Tabbing?](http://superuser.com/questions/413609/how-do-you-hide-the-finder-from-the-list-of-applications-when-command-tabbing) – should work the same for iTunes.

Comment: Thanks, that will do the trick together with the widget suggested by aliasgar

Comment: @aliasgar - If you read the [mac] wiki excerpt, it is for questions about Mac hardware. OS questions should use the relevant OSX tag, which was already there.  In fact, one or the other of the two OSX tags could be deleted as redundant.  Another question already had an [imac] tag, so adding [mac] is undesirable redundancy that dilutes searching by tag.  Adding [mac] to a bunch of questions where it doesn't add value dilutes the active questions queue and deprives visibility for new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is widget called `miniTunes` (not from Apple ofcourse, but works well!) which you can use: Go [Here](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard) and follow the screenshot I have attached!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but see my edit please. Its not what I was looking for. +1